Crystal report - replace empty fields with a finctional number
I am trying to replace empy field with a finctional number,
I am trying to set this formula,
if {OPCH.myfield} = '' then 123456789 else ({OPCH.myfield})
system has highlithed
else ({OPCH.myfield})
and asking me a number,
another option is to set this formula
*if isnull {OPCH.myfield} then 123456789 else ({OPCH.myfield})
*also in this case a mistake
someone could help me, please?
tried to set two formulas as descripted, but no results

The data type returned from IF THEN ELSE must be consistent. So change to something like:
if {OPCH.myfield} = '' then "123456789" else ({OPCH.myfield})


Hi, thanks for your reply, system return a message: FORMULA RESULT MUST BE A BOOLEAN

Please specify the data type of each element in your expressions.
Please show the expression you are using.
